# How can I define a symmetric relationship in Graql

Tags: vaticle-typeql

I'm trying to model the Modern dataset (http://www.tinkerpop.com/docs/3.0.0.M7/images/tinkerpop-modern.png) in Graql. Marko knows Vadas and Vadas knows Marko - for the purposes of this example, I'm assuming that they are friends.

So can I do this?

```
    insert friendship isa relation-type;
    insert friend isa role-type;
    insert friendship has-role friend, has-role friend;
```

All the examples I've seen so far, have two different roles on a relationship (e.g. teacher/student).

Answer (score 1):

Roles must be distinct, so you cannot have two `friend` roles in a single relation.

If the relation you are describing is symmetric, you should instead introduce two roles `friend1` and `friend2`. If you want, these can both be `ako friend`.

Given the dataset you're using, it might be better to not describe this as a symmetric relationship and instead uses a `knows` relationship, where one role is the `knower` and the other role is `known-about`.

Answer (score 0):

As Felix Chapman pointed out, role-types are unique, so a true symmetric relation is not possible.

There are a few ways around it; say you have defined your relation as

```
insert
friendship isa relation-type
  has-role friend1
  has-role friend2;
```

The first possibility is to use `ako` and abstract roles:

```
friend isa role-type is abstract;
friend1 ako friend;
friend2 ako friend;

person isa entity-type plays-role friend;
```

The second possibility is using [inference rules](https://mindmaps.io/pages/documentation/core-api/advanced-schema-definition.html):

```
SymmetricFriendship isa inference-rule,
  lhs {match (friend1 $x, friend2 $y) isa friendship;
       select $x, $y},
  rhs {match (friend1 $y, friend2 $x} isa friendship;};
```

The second way makes the friendship relation a true symmetric relation from a mathematical point of view, but given Graql's match syntax and for performance reasons, there is rarely the need to explicitly make a relation symmetric, so I personally prefer the first way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something symmetric by adding an `entity` that models a group of friends:

```
friendship sub relation,
  relates friend,
  relates friend-group;

person sub entity,
  plays friend;

group sub entity,
  plays friend-group;
```

This does feel like a kludge. The `friendship` relation effectively just expresses the subset relationship. I have used `group` instead of `pair` because now `friendship` is not binary any more, as I do not know how to restrict the number of `friend`s in a `friend-group`. Moreover, the same two friends can be part of multiple `friendship`s.

Graql as a modeling language would be more powerful if it would allow specifying variadic relations, e.g. using ranges for the number of role-players for each role. This would cover this use case as well:

```
friendship sub relation,
  relates 2 friend;
```

Comment: Apparently, in Grakn a `relation` is variadic by default: https://discuss.grakn.ai/t/symmetric-inverse-transitive-relationships/131/2. I will formulate a second answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the fact that any role can be repeated in a relationship instance:

```
friendship sub relation,
  relates friend;

name sub attribute,
  datatype string;

person sub entity,
  has name,
  plays friend;
```

Then you can say

```
insert $x isa Person, has name "X";
insert $y isa Person, has name "Y";
match
  $x isa Person, has name "X";
  $y isa Person, has name "Y";
insert $xy (friend: $x, friend: $y) isa friendship;
```